# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' yagmail and csv

Tags: python

This questions asked hundreds of times but I still can't sort out my own issue. When I run the py script I get this error in return.

Currently when I run the script I get the error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/CIB2019/Scripts/testarray.py", line 10, in 
    for name, email, message in line.strip().split(','):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

```
**Code Contents

import yagmail
import csv

wait = 15 #seconds in between messages

yag = yagmail.SMTP('email@gmail.com', 'password')

with open("mails.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        for name, email, message in line.strip().split(','):
            yag.send(email, subject = name, contents = message)
            print("sent")
            time.sleep(wait) 





**Mails.csv Contents

Name,Email,Message  
a,4236543542@txt.att.net,Meow1
b,9876543542@txt.att.net,Meow2
```

Logs into gmail smtp, opens mails.csv, send mail to each individual user, wait 15 seconds in-between sends to each individual user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csv.reader` generator parses the lines for you already so you don't need to `strip` and `split` the lines yourself:

```
for name, email, message in csv_reader:
    yag.send(email, subject = name, contents = message)
    print("sent")
    time.sleep(wait)
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you. Theirs just so many topics on it and answers.